# [Vue-Response ]In Crome 60 $http get returns response.data as string instead of json array

Tags: google-chrome, http, asp.net-web-api, vue.js

In all other browsers (including chrome 59) the api call returns response.data as a json array of objects.  However, in chrome 60, it is a string.

The request headers are set to accept application/json.
The response headers are set as Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8.

Why in the world is this breaking in Chrome 60?

Comment: What is the return type of your API or backend? does that returns object or string?

Comment: It returns a list of objects, and it sets the Content-Type to be application/json.  Yet, for some reason, in chrome 60, it sees this return as a string.  In all other browsers, including previous versions of chrome, it's a json array.

Comment: Turns out this was a vue-resource version issue... I updated to latest and all is well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your vue-resource version up to date will fix the problem.
(I've tried version 1.0.3 works well, my previous version is 0.9.1)